# Excel import and export to SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, excel

I have a requirement where I need to upload xsl (excel 2003) into SQL 2008R2 database. I am using ORCHAD stuff for scheduling.

I am using HTTPPOSTEDFILEBASE filestream to convert into byte array and store in database.

After storing background scheduler picks up the task and process the data stored. I need to create objects from data in excel and send for processing. I am struck at decoding byte array :(

What is the best way to handle this kinda requirement? any libraries which I make use.

My web app is build with MVC3, EF4.1,repository pattern, Autofaq.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the HTTPPOSTEDFILEBASE class, but you could:

1. Convert the file to a byte stream
2. Save it as the appropriate byte/blob type in your database (store the extension in a separate field)
3. Retrieve bytes and add the appropriate extension to the file stream
4. Treat as a normal file...

But I'm actually wondering if your requirements even demand this. Why are you storing the file in the first place? If you are only using the file data to shape your business object (that I'm guessing gets saved somewhere), you could perform that data extraction, shaping, and persistence before you store the file as raw bytes so you never have to reconstitute the file for that purpose.